# openfile issue on visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to finish a graphics processing tutorial and am stuck on the input file. My visual studio is not accepting the .txt file despite having it in the working directory and giving it the full path name (C:/ -> identifier is undefined) not sure why the first line is giving problems so any help understanding this would be really appreciated.

```
std::ifstream openfile(C:/Users/RDT/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/TDS1/TDS1/Maps1.txt);
sf::Texture tileTexture;
sf::Sprite tiles;

sf::Vector2i map[100][100];
sf::Vector2i loadCounter = sf::Vector2i(0, 0);
    if (openfile.is_open())
    {
        std::string tileLocation;
        openfile >> tileLocation;
        tileTexture.loadFromFile(tileLocation);
        tiles.setTexture(tileTexture);
        while (!openfile.eof())
        {
            std::string str;
            openfile >> str;
            char x = str[0], y = str[2];
            if (!isdigit(x) || !isdigit(y))
                map[loadCounter.x][loadCounter.y] = sf::Vector2i(-1, -1);
            else
                map[loadCounter.x][loadCounter.y] = sf::Vector2i(x-'0', y-'0');
            if (openfile.peek() == '\n')
            {
                loadCounter.x = 0;
                loadCounter.y++;
            }
            else
                loadCounter.x++;
        }
        loadCounter.y++;
    }
    sf::RenderWindow Window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480, 32), "Loading Maps");
    while (Window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event Event;
        while (Window.pollEvent(Event))
        {
            switch (Event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                    Window.close();
                    break;
            }
        }
        Window.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < loadCounter.x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < loadCounter.x; j++)
            {
                if (map[i][j].x != -1 && map[i][j].y != -1)
                {
                    tiles.setPosition(i * 32, j * 32);
                    tiles.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(map[i][j].x = 32, map[i][j].y = 32, 32, 32));
                    Window.draw(tiles);
                }
            }
        }
        Window.display();

    }
```

}

Comment: You **do** know you have to surround string literals with double-quotes, right? And you also need to escape some values? And that on Windows the path separator is backslash, not forward slash?

Comment: @Ken Forwardslash will work OK with the C++ stream library.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Yes, I know. But the Windows path separator is the backslash, and it's clearly Windows specific code because of the use of `C:`. I'm not sure if the poster is aware of that, however, which is why I pointed it out.

Comment: @Ken I meant that VS/VC++ will accept both.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Yes, I already said I was aware of that in my last comment. I also explained why I pointed it out to the poster (again, in my last comment). I probably should have said *And BTW, on Windows*, though.

Answer (score 0):

Everything else looks okay in your code except path provided to `openfile()` constructor. I'll suggest a simple change to fix this problem. The problem is in path to file.

```
1. Move Maps1.txt fine in `C:\ProgramData\` folder. 

2. change your 1st line in program as:

    std::ifstream openfile("C:\\ProgramData\\Maps1.txt");
```